# How to upcast a monad transformer type?

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats

Using Cats, is there a better/more idiomatic way to do this?

```
class Foo
class Bar extends Foo

val eithertBar = EitherT.apply(SomeMonad(Right[Whatever, Bar](new Bar)))
val eithertFoo = EitherT[SomeMonad, Whatever, Foo].apply(eithertBar.value)
```

Extracting the value and re-applying it feels a bit odd. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for any functor `F` Cats provides a `widen` syntax method that can do what you're requesting. So if you have this (using `Eval` as the `F` for the sake of example):

```
class Foo
class Bar extends Foo

import cats.Eval, cats.data.EitherT, cats.syntax.functor._

val eithertBar = EitherT[Eval, String, Bar](Eval.now(Right(new Bar)))
```

You can write this:

```
scala> eithertBar.widen[Foo]
res0: cats.data.EitherT[cats.Eval,String,Foo] = EitherT(Now(Right(Bar@5ab3a323)))
```

Note that if the `F` was a standard library type constructor (such as `Option`), or some other type constructor that didn't have a `Functor` instance in its companion object, you'd have to make sure to import or otherwise provide a `Functor` for it in order for this to work.